# Table border is missing for bootstrap responsive table view

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, html-table

I am getting a weird problem from data table view in Firefox browser.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="viewData">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-left tbl-head" align="left"></th>
                <th class="text-left tbl-head" align="left">people Name</th>
                <th class="text-left tbl-head" align="left">Email</th>
                <th class="text-left tbl-head" align="left">City</th>
                <th class="text-left tbl-head" align="left">Country</th>
                <th class="text-left tbl-head" align="left"> Time</th>
                <th class="text-left tbl-head" align="left">Subject</th>
                <th class="text-left tbl-head" align="left">Message</th>
                <th class="text-left tbl-head" align="left">Status</th>
                <th class="text-left tbl-head" align="left">Reply</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="dataView">
            <tr id="631" class="tbl-bg-color">
                <td class="text-left" align="left"><input  type="checkbox"></td>
                <td class="text-left" align="left">shamim</td>
                <td class="text-left" align="left">xyz@gmail.com</td>
                <td class="text-left" align="left">washington</td>
                <td class="text-left" align="left">usa</td>
                <td class="text-left" align="left">18-Mar-15</td>
                <td class="text-left" align="left">hi</td>
                <td class="text-left" align="left">hi</td>
                <td class="text-left" align="left">UnReplied</td>
                <td class="text-left" align="left"><button class="btn-primary btn btn-bg">Reply</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="619" class="tbl-bg-color">
                <td class="text-left" align="left"><input  type="checkbox"></td>
                <td class="text-left" align="left">test</td>
                <td class="text-left" align="left">test@yahoo.co</td>
                <td class="text-left" align="left">washington</td>
                <td class="text-left" align="left">usa</td>
                <td class="text-left" align="left">15-Mar-15</td>
                <td class="text-left" align="left">123123</td>
                <td class="text-left" align="left">123123</td>
                <td class="text-left" align="left">Replied</td>
                <td class="text-left" align="left"><button class="btn-primary btn btn-bg">Reply</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="596"  class="tbl-bg-color">
                <td class="text-left" align="left"><input  type="checkbox"></td>
                <td class="text-left" align="left">monir</td>
                <td class="text-left" align="left">vvv@yahoo.com</td>
                <td class="text-left" align="left">india</td>
                <td class="text-left" align="left">-</td>
                <td class="text-left" align="left">06-Mar-15</td>
                <td class="text-left" align="left">test</td>
                <td class="text-left" align="left">hii...test</td>
                <td class="text-left" align="left">Replied</td>
                <td class="text-left" align="left"><button class="btn-primary btn btn-bg">Reply</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="594" class="tbl-bg-color">
                <td class="text-left" align="left"><input  type="checkbox"></td>
                <td class="text-left" align="left">t mob</td>
                <td class="text-left" align="left">t@y.com</td>
                <td class="text-left" align="left">washington</td>
                <td class="text-left" align="left">-</td>
                <td class="text-left" align="left">06-Mar-15</td>
                <td class="text-left" align="left">hi</td>
                <td class="text-left" align="left">hi bb</td>
                <td class="text-left" align="left">UnReplied</td>
                <td class="text-left" align="left"><button class="btn-primary btn btn-bg">Reply</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I have pasted my code. Here when I zoom in my Firefox browser, it is missing few border lines. When I view 80% resolution, I am getting right border of email column is missing.

What is the problem of bootstrap for Firefox browser? In other browsers, I am not getting the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From other answers, ensure your zoom level is at 100% otherwise firefox will have issues trying to collapse the borders.

Ctrl + 0 will reset your zoom.

Responsive sites are more about reducing the size of the browser window not a zoom level.